# When to use detach

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch, gradient, detach

If I have two different neural networks (parametrized by model1 and model2) and corresponding two optimizers, would the below operation using model2.parameters without detach() lead to change in its gradients? My requirement is that I want to just compute the mean squared loss between the two model parameters but update the optimizer corresponding to model1, leaving model2 as is.

```
opt1 = torch.optim.SGD(self.model1.parameters(), lr=1e-3)
opt2 = torch.optim.SGD(self.model2.parameters(), lr=1e-3)

loss = (self.lamb / 2.) * ((torch.nn.utils.parameters_to_vector(self.model1.parameters()) - torch.nn.utils.parameters_to_vector(self.model2.parameters()))**2).sum()

loss.backward()
opt1.step()
```

How can I decide in general whether to use detach for any operation or not?

Comment: Without detach, the gradients for both of them will be computed, but you'll only optimize opt1-related params in this snippet. If you have a `opt2.step()` later, then be careful.

Comment: yes, I do have opt2.step() later. Would the above operation change the computation graph of model2.parameters?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "change the computation graph of model2.parameters" in this context. What I can tell you is that without detaching `model2.parameters`, `loss.backward()` will compute `.grad` for all the params (except if you disabled some them before). Therefore, if you call opt2.step() later, you'll be considering these gradients as well (unless you zero them out right before).